# howt to use .MDF file

Tags: sql-server

work on SQL Server 2000.i have **CustomerDetails_Data.MDF** file .from this file i want to take all information on my database .How to do?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to attach the .mdf data file to a database in SQL Server. Then you can simply query the information.

If you just have an .mdf file (and no log file .ldf), follow these steps to create a Database from your lone .mdf file:

> 1. Create a new database with the same name and same MDF and LDF files
> 2. Stop sql server and rename the existing MDF to a new one and copy the
>      original MDF to this location and
>      delete the LDF files.
> 3. Start SQL Server
> 4. Now your database will be marked suspect 5. Update the sysdatabases to
>      update to Emergency mode. This will
>      not use LOG files in start up

```
     Sp_configure "allow updates", 1
     go
     Reconfigure with override
     GO
     Update sysdatabases set status = 32768 where name = "BadDbName"
     go
     Sp_configure "allow updates", 0
     go
     Reconfigure with override
     GO
```

> 6. Restart sql server. now the database will be in emergency mode
> 7. Now execute the undocumented DBCC to create a log file
>
>    DBCC REBUILD_LOG(dbname,'c:\dbname.ldf') --
>      Undocumented step to create a new log
>      file.
>
> (replace the dbname and log file name
>   based on your requirement)
>
> 8. Execute `sp_resetstatus <dbname>`
> 9. Restart SQL server and see the database is online.

Comment: SQL server will automatically generate the log file after attaching the database, no need to make it like this way...

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the .mdf data file to SQL Server, and SQL server will automatically generate a new LOG file, after that you can pass any query to the database...

Answer (score -1):

What format do you want to extract the information to?  You could write sql scripts against it, or use bulk copy.